Why is the Outlook Application_ItemSend function receiving a string?
I am currently facing some issues trying to write an Outlook macro that fires when an Item is sent.
When the Application_ItemSend sub fires, the value for Item is not a olMailItem as expected, but rather a string that just contains the subject of the message. Here is the simple code that is currently running. It obviously does nothing, but it illustrates the issue I'm seeing.
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Item Is MailItem Then
        x = Item.Subject
        
    End If

End Sub

Here is the message I am trying to send:

When I click send, I get a 424 (Object Required) error message from the VBA console:

I then click debug and hover over the "Item" keyword, and I see that it's not an object as expected, but just a string set to the value of the subject field:

Am I completely misguided in how this predefined sub should work? Is there some weird AD setting from my company causing this?
I realize that this might not be reproducable, but I'm hoping that someone can provide some insight.
Thanks!

Should be If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then   Hovering over Item displays its default property  Subject, not (eg) "[object]"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.subject#:~:text=The%20Subject%20property%20is%20the%20default%20property%20for%20Outlook%20items.

Well that solved my problem. I'm embarrassed that I didn't notice that before posting, but thank you for holding my hand!
